Is python gzip.open not fully implemented on Windows?
At least on my system (Windows 11 Enterprise, Python 3.12.2), using gzip.open(filename, 'wb') to write a compressed file creates an empty .gz file, despite reporting having written data.
Minimal example:
import os
import gzip

data = b'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
written = gzip.open('D:\\tmp\\try1.gz', 'wb').write(data)
compressed_written = os.stat('D:\\tmp\\try1.gz').st_size
print("theoretically written", written, "B, compressed size is", compressed_written, "B")

Which prints out (on my system): theoretically written 445 B, compressed size is 0 B
Is this expected behaviour due to it not being supported on Windows, or is this a bug? (and if so, where should I report it?)
Thanks!
P.S.: Same thing occurs when using a with statement block.

Show the code with with. Likely you did the same mistake there.

And is the file actually empty after the script finishes?

Have you verified the output of os.stat independently? Like, try len(open(path, 'rb').read())

Your code (with import gzip and import os) works fine for me on Win 11 with Python 3.10.11

@nocomment the minimal example with with seems to work, but my original code that made me come here still doesn't, and that was with a with statement: with open(path, 'wb') as w:             pickle.dump((self.gene, self.info), w, protocol = pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

@juanpa.arrivillaga yes, the file is actually empty, I just used os.stat to show that in the minimal example

@NebularNerd that is so weird, seems to be a local bug on my installation then? It is very strange behaviour

@MichaelButscher fair point – I assumed that the garbage collector takes care of that (like it does with a normal open statement), but I suppose that doesn't have to be the case, thanks for that

do you have a custom Python build? DUring Python compiling it will link with the gzip libraries that are available  -the build enviroment used by your Python install might be featuring a bogus gzip library.  If this was general, even if only for the official windows builds, it would affect too many people, to the point a release fixing the problem would have been made - no one lives without pickle

@OdedR.  If the gzip file object has an internal cyclic references, garbage collection can be indefinitely delayed on the CPython reference interpreter. On other interpreters, this can happen even without a cyclic reference, which is why you shouldn't rely on the file to have any contents until the with block completes, or you've manually flush-ed the file. Just because it sometimes, or even often, works with open doesn't mean you should ever use file-like objects without with statements.
